# Ruby regex replace substring with hash pattern

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I have to replace strings in a hash. I have:

```
hash = {"{STAY_ID}"=>"30030303", "{USER_NAME}"=>"test"}
```

And I have to replace it here:

```
str = "www.domain.com?person={STAY_ID}&user={USER_NAME}"
#=> www.domain.com?person=30030303&user=test
```

Also, it should work when there is a string with at least one match:

```
str = "www.domain.com?person={STAY_ID}"

#=> www.domain.com?person=30030303
```

I need some method/solution that can handle any situation like above.

Comment: "I need some regex": no, you don't need some regex.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Okey, I've updated my question..

Comment: Different approach. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something great about the `gsub` method is that it can actually take a hash of mappings as the second argument, which it then uses to replace matched values. Therefore, if you regex any text between curly braces, you can do something like this.

```
str = "www.domain.com?person={STAY_ID}&user={USER_NAME}"

hash = {
 "{STAY_ID}"=>"30030303", 
 "{USER_NAME}"=>"test"
}

str.gsub(/{(.*?)}/, hash) #www.domain.com?person=30030303&user=test
```

And then ya done!

Comment: Nice... Do you have any idea how I can do reversible? To remove all uris that doesn't contain  at least one of those ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that you'd also want it to delete any unmapped variables? Like: `"www.domain.com?person={NO_WEHRE}"` becomes `"www.domain.com?person="`

Comment: No problem! Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I think, regex is not readable solution. You can use simple `gsub` method:

```rb
str = "www.domain.com?person={STAY_ID}&user={USER_NAME}"
hash = {"{STAY_ID}"=>"30030303", "{USER_NAME}"=>"test"}

result_str = hash.inject(str.dup) do |acc, (key, value)|
  acc = acc.gsub(key, value)
end

result_str # www.domain.com?person=30030303&user=test
```

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav Zharkov ! Works like a charm!